# IDA Pro jumping to offset from base

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I use CheatEngine as a debugger (and get a lot of crap for it). When I find addresses, I always write them down based on the offset from where the start of the instructions are (e.g. program.exe+402C0). It would be nice to be able to use the goto function with this method of referencing a location; is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to IDA Pro's documentation:

> If the entered [goto] string can not be recognized as a hexadecimal or location name, IDA will try to interpreet it as an expression using the current script interpreter. The default interpreter is IDC.

So what you can do is define a global variable in the IDC interpreter (using the bar at the bottom of your IDA view) that identifies the base address of your module as such:

```
extern ModuleBaseAddress;
ModuleBaseAddress = 0x400000; // Example base address
```

Then whenever you want to go to the base address + offset you would simply open the Jump window (using the g-key) and type in:

```
ModuleBaseAddress + 0x1000 // 0x1000 is your offset
```